# Is there a way to create and export a Swift dynamic framework without exposing the implementation?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I've got an iOS dynamic framework written in Swift and would like to know what ways I can "export" the framework for use in external projects, while leaving the implementation unexposed.

The "best" solution I've come across so far is from [this article](https://kodmunki.wordpress.com/2015/09/22/ios-9-universal-cocoa-touch-frameworks/), but for some reason autocompletion stops working when I'm trying to use classes from the framework in a project.

Right now I'm using a Xcode workspace to use the framework within a project. However, as mentioned I don't want to have the implementation exposed.

I understand that Swift doesn't have separate interface and implementation files found in Objective-C, but am just curious as to how other people approach this.